# discord.py purge command not working and no error

Tags: python, discord.py, purge

So I want to purge the message of a particular member. This is my code.

```
@commands.command()
async def purge_member(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=100, check=lambda message: message.author == member)
```

The problem is the messages of the member are not getting purged.
It does not show any error either.

I have tried many other methods instead of purge to delete but all of them refuse to work, with no errors

Comment: Do you have an `on_message` event?

Comment: Yes, but not in the main folder. Only in the cogs.

Comment: You should probably put an `on_message` event in your main python file and make sure to also load your cog extensions.

Comment: Is there any reason you have a comment marker `#`? This comments your code and won't run it.

Comment: Probably has it because the code won't work. I usually put it there when mine does not work so I can work on it later and not have any current errors. He might have also just copied and pasted the code from the cog into here, so I don't know if he forgot to remove it.

Comment: well my cog extensions are loaded. I have been trying this since log before, before I had as on_message event also. But it never worked. Like Garrett said, I forgot to remove the # but yeah even without it , it doesnt work. Also I'm a girl.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `on_message` event, add `process_commands` at the end of it

```py
# In Cog
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(m):
    ...
    await self.bot.process_commands(m)

# In Main File
@bot.event
async def on_message(m):
    ...
    await bot.process_commands(m)
```

If you have not un-commented the code do it else it won't work

```
# In Cog
@commands.command()
async def purge_member(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=100, check=lambda message: message.author == member)

# In Main File
@bot.command()
async def purge_member(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=100, check=lambda message: message.author == member)
```

Comment: even with procces_commands it doesnt work. I have already tried that. The code is uncommented.